# How does the $p+p + e^-\rightarrow D + \gamma\gamma+ \nu$ reaction proceed in the sun?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fusion

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChTJHEdf6yM) on nuclear fusion the explanation of the reaction $p+p\rightarrow D + \nu + \gamma\gamma$ is that the two protons collide, form a weakly bound state, and then sometimes decay into the right hand side via inverse beta decay. Call that 
$$p + p + e^- \rightarrow pp + e^-\rightarrow D + e^+ + e^- + \nu \rightarrow D + \gamma\gamma + \nu.$$

Another way for this process to occur is for the inverse beta decay to happen first, that is
\begin{align}
    p + p + e^- &\rightarrow p + n + \nu + \gamma\gamma &&\rightarrow D + \nu + \gamma\gamma,\text{ or} \\
    p + p + e^- &\rightarrow p + n + e^+ + \nu + e^- &&\rightarrow D + \nu + \gamma\gamma.
\end{align}

In the core of the sun which chain contributes more, overall, to the deuterium production? I know that the first reaction needs the inverse beta decay to happen during a very short window while the di-proton exists. The latter is less constrained by that, but is hampered by the virtual neutron. So, I'd be especially interested to see how the numbers shake out.

Comment: Why do you say "virtual neutron"? Inverse beta decay can be $p + e \rightarrow n + \nu_e$.

Comment: @RobJeffries Right! The neutron is still virtual (it's not on an external leg). Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Inverse beta decay produces real neutrons. I still don't understand your use of "virtual".

Comment: Are you sure that that should be an electron (instead of a positron) in the title?

Comment: @RobJeffries Any particle without any external legs on the overall Feynman diagram is virtual, right? The overall Feynman diagram starts with two protons and an electron, and ends with a deuteron, neutrino, and some photons. Everything else exists for a very short time, and is, therefore, virtual. Strictly speaking, inverse beta decay is a process with many Feynman diagrams. I'm actually only referring to the lowest order diagram for that decay as a sub-diagram of this process.

Answer (score 6):

The temperature in the core of the Sun is about 1.3 keV.

Inverse beta decay, in the form
$$ p + e \rightarrow n + \nu_e$$
(or some variant thereof) requires the kinetic energy of the proton and electron to *at least* make up the mass difference $(m_n - m_p - m_e)c^2 =  0.785$ MeV.

The rate of neutronisation is therefore vanishingly small.

If I have my use of Wolfram Integrator correct, then the fraction of particles in the tail of the M-B distribution with $E/k_BT > 603$ is $\sim 10^{-261}$ so neutronisation of free protons just doesn't happen.

By a process of elimination it must therefore be the first option - weak force alteration of the diproton to deuterium -  that dominates.